# Install-PackageProvider NuGet failing on docker even with TLS12 present

Tags: docker, powershell, docker-for-windows

I am trying to install Nuget package manager in a docker image

```
WARNING: MSG:UnableToDownload
«https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=627338&clcid=0x409» «»
WARNING: Unable to download from URI
'https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=627338&clcid=0x409' to ''.
WARNING: Unable to download the list of available providers. Check your
internet connection.
Install-PackageProvider : No match was found for the specified search criteria
for the provider 'NuGet'. The package provider requires 'PackageManagement'
and 'Provider' tags. Please check if the specified package has the tags.
At line:1 char:128
+ ... :SecurityProtocol; Install-PackageProvider -Name NuGet -Force ; [Net. ...
+                        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (Microsoft.Power...PackageProvi
   der:InstallPackageProvider) [Install-PackageProvider], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NoMatchFoundForProvider,Microsoft.PowerShell.Pac
   kageManagement.Cmdlets.InstallPackageProvider
```

Tls 12 is present on the machine. I have set the user to Container admin

```
USER ContainerAdministrator
```

Output of

```
RUN powershell [Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12 ; [Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol; Install-PackageProvider -Name NuGet -Force ; [Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol
```

is

```
Tls12
WARNING: MSG:UnableToDownload
«https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=627338&clcid=0x409» «»
WARNING: Unable to download from URI
'https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=627338&clcid=0x409' to ''.
WARNING: Unable to download the list of available providers. Check your
internet connection.
Install-PackageProvider : No match was found for the specified search criteria
for the provider 'NuGet'. The package provider requires 'PackageManagement'
and 'Provider' tags. Please check if the specified package has the tags.
At line:1 char:128
+ ... :SecurityProtocol; Install-PackageProvider -Name NuGet -Force ; [Net. ...
+                        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (Microsoft.Power...PackageProvi
   der:InstallPackageProvider) [Install-PackageProvider], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NoMatchFoundForProvider,Microsoft.PowerShell.Pac
   kageManagement.Cmdlets.InstallPackageProvider

Tls, Tls11, Tls12
```

**Details about the image:**

Base image: mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:ltsc2019

PS Version: 5.1.17763.4644